# Is it a good practice to calculate and override hashCode once for ever

Tags: java

I work with the OpenSource OODB [db4o](http://community.versant.com/Downloads.aspx) and my serialized classes inherit from a common abstract.class which have two fields :

```
. . .
private final Long timeCreate = (System.currentTimeMillis() << 20) + (System.nanoTime() & 0xfffff);
private final int hashCode = timeCreate.hashCode();
. . . 
@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    return hashCode;
}
. . .
```

Is it a good practice to so?

The benchmarks I've tried give faster responses, but is a pitfall nested some where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally a hashCode of an object shouldn't change in any case. One option is to only generate it on demand but in your case you have the problem that the timeCreate is not sure to be unique or monotonically increasing.  System.nanoTime() can produce the same value over 1000 times if you only have micro-second resolution.

```
private static final AtomicLong TIME_ID = new AtomicLong(0);
private static long generateTimeId() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000;
    long id = TIME_ID.getAndIncrement();
    if (id > now)
        return id;
    TIME_ID.compareAndSet(id+1, now);
    return TIME_ID.getAndIncrement();
}

// produce a monotonically increasing time id.
private final long timeCreate = generateTimeId();
private final int hashCode = (int)((timeCreate >> 32) ^ timeCreate);
```

Note: if two objects are equals == true, they must have the same hashCode.

Comment: In my code `<< 20 ~= * 1000000`, so adding nano part (`"[000000]$"`) of time to a millisecond time have ever product a 200 nanosecond minimal elapse time in test I've made to research collision/equality of timeCreate, even with Thread on a 2.8 GHz CPU. But I know it it not perfect - I've tested AtomicLong, it is time eager - equals() is also overrided

Comment: The only point about nanotime is that it will go backwards in the same `(1 << 20)` cycle. AtomicLong is *much* faster than making a system call.

Comment: I've never imagine this :  `Long timeCreate  = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()).get()`, is the good solution? : I use millisecond because timeCreate is significant (and nanotime is not)

Comment: I would use a `long` rather than `Long`. You can use `new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000)` with `getAndIncrement()` if you might create more than 1000 objects per second

Comment: Thanks, I'll review my code to have `long` in serialized classes and cast it only when needed, and I'll study if I maintain `<<20` or less with AtomicLong. Thanks again, good help for me. Claude

Answer (score 0):

generally hashcode are determined based on object's state, if you don't consider object's state while calculating hashcode you need to take care of `hashcode()` and `equals()` relationship

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there doesn't really sit right with the [contract for hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

In your system, unless two objects are created at exactly the same time, they do not have the same hashCode, so you may as well use the default implementation of the `Object` class whereby  it considers two object to be different if they are different instances (which is what happens here).

If that is what is desired, I would remove that custom code...